# Trouble specifying dates in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, api

I am using the following to extract Facebook posts and comments using the following request:

```
 `me?fields=posts{comments}`
```

which works fine.

When i try to specify some date range using:

`me?fields=posts{comments}?period=2016-11-01&until=2019-12-02`

i get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"?\".\" at character 15: posts{comments}?period",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2500,
"fbtrace_id": "AlvbffL63STHI2nxm3ANsh2"
}
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I am new to Facebook API, and any help will be much appreciated

Comment: The URL query string _starts_ with a question mark, but multiple name=value parameters are _separated_ using an ampersand.

Comment: Hi 04FS, thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me how it should like since I am still not able to make it work?